# How to get pandas crosstab margins value?

Tags: pandas

I got a set of crosstab dataframe which looks like below

```
Batch     1   2   3   4   All 
Fruits
Orange    2   3   4   5    14
Mango     3   2   1   7    13
Grape     2   2   2   2     8
Apple     5   5   8   9    27
All       13  14  18  27   62
```

The 'All' column and row is generated by the pandas crosstab's margins parameter, so my question is that how can I get the 'All' data by column, which is 13, 14, 18 and 27?

Comment: Use `df.iloc[-1, :-1]`.

Comment: thanks @jezrael , it works well